# Creating custom GPS maps for WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, mobile, gps

So basically I am trying to create a custom GPS map for my WP7 application. I did find a great [website](http://www.robomatt.com/maps/makemaps_paper.html) with step by step instructions.

But in this example they used a program called OziExplorer. I tried to get this program and now i have 3versions of it. which are(I don't know which to use):

1. oziexplorer 3d
2. oziexplorer ce
3. oziexplorer pc

What i figured was that oziexplorer can only be used for windows pocket pc meaning winmo6.5 so i dont know if this is compatible with WP7.

I did find another website where an actual wp7 app has been released that allows a user to take a picture of a map and calibrate it with 2 points of location and the image can then be used as a gps map.

If anyone could possibly point me in the right direction as to how to begin creating a custom map to use in a wp7 app I would be ever so grateful. The map is supposed to be a map of a park.

Thanks in advance for everyones help and sorry if i sound like a noob..its just google has finally failed me..

Regards

shan

Comment: Why not use the built in Bing Maps?

Comment: the parks are always just a green patch on bing maps. so i still have to draw the paths and stuff out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach I've seen for making map tiles is to use Microsoft MapCruncher -  see http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/mapcruncher/ and http://www.bdcc.co.uk/GoogleCrunch/Crunch.htm - this enables you to build custom tiles for an overlay.

This blog - http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.com/2010/10/showing-open-source-maps-on-windows.html - tells you how to show custom tiles within the Bing Maps Silverlight viewer.

I would guess (don't know) that OziExplorer tiles could be used in this way - you just need to find a way to map the tile co-ordinates to a custom tile layer.

Another option for you is to use OpenStreetMap data:

- You can use CloudMade's services - www.cloudmade.com - to produce map tiles with customised look-and-feel.
- You can produce your own tiles using MapNik - but (as I'm sure you are already aware) the processing and storage size needed for map tiles is large

Comment: Hi stuart. Thanks for the links! I guess you just gave me a step by step. Create a custom tile and using it within bing maps. Now i just have to try it out. Thanks again. hopefully i can get it to work=)